# How to combine podSelector with ports in Kubernetes Network Policy?

Tags: networking, kubernetes

I have a pod called **mysql-1** with ports 3306 and 3307 open.
I want to create a network policy that allow ingress connection from **backend-1** to 3306 and **backend-2** to 3307.
Right now all I could come up with is this policy:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: mysql-ingress-policy-1
  namespace: v2ci
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql-1
      release: v2
  types:
  - Ingress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: backend-1
          release: v2
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: backend-1
          release: v2
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3307
```

The problem is that with this policy each backend pod has access to both ports.
Is it possible to combine `ports` with `podSelector` somehow or should I just create one network policy for each backend pod?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no obvious way to achieve such behavior. Thus, creating two network policies look like viable option.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion too. I also looked through the k8s code to see if there's a way to combine ports and podSelectors, I didn't find any. I guess this is by design. as you said, It should be two different network policies.

Comment: I can't see the label `backend-2` in this yaml file. But apart from that, you can provide two different `- from` sections...

Answer (score 0):

There is no `backend-2` mentioned in your yaml file, but changing only that would not lead to the desired result.

You have to provide two different `- from` sections, one per backend:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: mysql-ingress-policy-1
  namespace: v2ci
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql-1
      release: v2
  types:
  - Ingress
  ingress:
  # route backend-1 to port 3306
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: backend-1
          release: v2
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3306
  # route backend-2 to port 3307
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: backend-2  # really apply a different pod than in the other "from"
          release: v2
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3307
```